# UnknownOperationException is always returned by Amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, mechanicalturk

I have created a queue and also given the permission as (*). 
The URL of my queue is https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/123/Example

When I hit this URL it always gives the output as `<UnknownOperationException/>`
. I checked the Chrome console it shows me following error. Can  anybody suggest what is the issue ? Or it is a bug ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not POST request. It is GET. The API endpoint is like this

```
http://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789012/testQueue/
?Action=ReceiveMessage
&WaitTimeSeconds=10
&MaxNumberOfMessages=5
&VisibilityTimeout=15
&AttributeName=All;
&Version=2012-11-05
&Expires=2013-10-25T22%3A52%3A43PST
&AUTHPARAMS
```

I was not mentioning the request parameters so not getting the result. That was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain what do you mean by hit the url? Aws only supports http post requests so if you try to go to this url using browser then you won't get any response but what you got on your browser. 
You need to send a valid request to this endpoint which contains the authentication info and a request object at the least.

Comment: What authentication info it needs ? Is there any document how to read messages from SQS ?

Comment: Yes i got the document as well. Here it is. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html